# See/Change underlying storage of Azure function app

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

Whenever I create a new Azure function app in the Azure, I select a storage account for it to use.

When the app is created, how do I see/change the storage account?

I have tried to poke around in the portal and have not been able to see that where I can configure this.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Once it is created you cannot modify the storage account, But you should be able to see the storage account and the related files on the Azure portal

You can see the settings of the configured Storage Account by navigating to **`Function App Settings -> Manage Application Settings ->`**

in the settings you can see the Key **`AzureWebJobsStorage`**

[image]

Comment: I acknowledge that i can't change it, but where do i see which storage account i originally chose?

Comment: What happens if you update this with a new storage account key?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the storage account, you just have to update the configuration to point to the access keys of the different storage account. Depending on the function this may be the AzureWebJobsStorage and WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING strings. Then, redeploy the function app.

Answer (score -1):

1.Click on Advanced Tools

2.Clock on go link where it takes to ***** scm.azurewebsites.net/api/settings

you can view like below,,

deployment_branch   "master"
SCM_TRACE_LEVEL "1"
SCM_COMMAND_IDLE_TIMEOUT    "60"
SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT   "7200"
SCM_BUILD_ARGS  ""
aspnet:PortableCompilationOutput    "true"
aspnet:PortableCompilationOutputSnapshotType    "Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots.SnapshotHelper, Microsoft.Web.Compilation.Snapshots, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1234567"
aspnet:DisableFcnDaclRead   "true"
SCM_GIT_USERNAME    "windowsazure"
SCM_GIT_EMAIL   "windowsazure"